# Is there any elegant way to replicate redis data cross aws regions with minimal latency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, architecture

Need to replicate redis data across other aws regions with minimal latency.

Comment: cross region replication of redis would cost you some latency. Its better to keep replication slave in different zone of same region.